# Implicit Grant with Evernote API or How to ship a native application using Evernote API

Tags: oauth, evernote

I have written a native application to sync data with Evernote and I would like to use the implicit grant flow, because I don't have an idea how to store the client secret in a safe way.

Are there plans to support OAuth 2.0 implicit grant by Evernote?

Any other suggestions how to implement and a ship a native application accessing the Evernote API without exposing the client secret?